# How to create spaces in a textbox?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vector, space, euclidean-distance

I have a vb net program to take a binary value in the image. This syntax produces

```
111110
```

on textbox3.text. I want no spaces at textbox3.text

```
1 1 1 1 1 0
```

---

```
        Dim x, y As Integer
        Dim gambar As New Bitmap(PictureBox7.Image)
        Dim gray, vektor, biner As Integer

        'biner
        'With gambar
        For x = 0 To gambar.Width - 1
            For y = 0 To gambar.Height - 1
                gray = (CInt(gambar.GetPixel(x, y).R) + _
                             gambar.GetPixel(x, y).G + _
                             gambar.GetPixel(x, y).B) / 3
                gambar.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(gray, gray, gray))

                If gray > 128 Then
                    biner = 255
                Else
                    biner = 0
                End If
                gambar.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(biner, biner, biner))
                'ttup proses grayscale
                If (biner = 0) Then
                    vektor = 0
                End If
                If (biner = 255) Then
                    vektor = 1
                End If
                'TextBox2.Text = pixel_putihblkg2
                TextBox3.SelectedText = vektor.ToString
            Next y
            PictureBox7.Refresh()
            PictureBox7.Image = gambar
        Next x
        PictureBox7.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage

    Catch exc As Exception
    End Try
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your request is unclear, but if I interpret your example correctly, you want to insert a space between each digit in your string before assigning it to the TextBox. You can do this with a modified loop and [String.Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Dim spacedString As String = vektor.ToString
For i As Integer = 0 To (spacedString.Length * 2) Step 2
    spacedString = spacedString.Insert(i + 1, " ")
Next
TextBox3.Text = spacedString
```

Here I'm copying `vektor.ToString` into a new variable, which will then be modified. The `For` loop increments from zero to twice the length of the unmodified string (because the final string will be twice as long), and steps by two (to insert after each character plus space, or two positions). For each iteration, use `.Insert` to insert a space. Finally, assign the modified string to the TextBox.

This will result in an extra space at the end of the string. If this is a problem, you can use [String.TrimEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove it.

```
TextBox3.Text = spacedString.TrimEnd(" "c)
```

**Update:** I failed to notice that you seem to be inserting one digit at a time to the TextBox. In this case you can simply add the spaces directly in code.

```
TextBox3.Text &= vektor.ToString & " "
```